# Excel and self generating purchase order numbers

Tags: excel

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to create a formula that creates a new purchase order number every time I open up my purchase order form on excel. The current cell the number goes into is E5.

My hope is that by doing this it will eliminate duplicate numbers. They would start at 0100 starting in January.

I've searched the web for an answer but haven't found one.

Can anyone here help me?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Don't think there is a way to do this using just formulas; but if you are willing to use VBA then it might be possible.

Comment: do you store the previous purchase order numbers somewhere in the spreadsheet that holds the form?

Comment: What is VBA?  And not currently storing previous numbers.

Comment: Unless you store your previous number and can 'lock it' against being observed by two users, you are just opening yourself up for duplicate number problems. You might want to go the next step and take a look at MS-Access. Also I would advise against attaching 'real world' meanings to invoice numbers. Just make at an incrementing number or you will run into all sorts of problems

Answer (score 0):

So Using VBA, You can easily update the value of a cell when ever the excel sheet is opened.

Given your order number in row E5 this is the code you would add to the workbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Cells(5, 5).Value = Cells(5, 5).Value + 1
End Sub
```

This piece will always update your cell value and add 1 to it whenever you open your excel sheet.

There are a couple of steps that you need to follow to get the code in your excel. Depending on your version of excel, first you will have to enable developer mode on your excel workbook you can do that by following instructions here.

Click the Microsoft Office Button Office button image, and then click Excel Options. Click Popular, and then select the Show Developer tab in the Ribbon check box.

Once you have developer mode enabled, you should be able to see a developer tab in the ribbons, click on the developer tab and then in the developer ribbon, you should be able to see the editor option, click on editor.

once you have clicked on editor, you would see a list of options in a small window, double click on "This Workbook" there. An editor window will open, and you need to copy and paste the code I have mentioned above there.

Finally save the excel sheet as xlsm (Macro Enabled sheet). And you should be all set.

Comment: You can download a sample file with this macro here . . .
http://expirebox.com/download/9dc7fcc13190699596017e5b1f0b12d9.html

Comment: Updated the answer . . .

Comment: In case you have trouble following the instructions, pm me with your excel sheet and I will update it for you :-). And oh! don't forget to mark my answer as accepted and upvote it. Thanks!

Comment: I can't seem to pm you :(

Comment: It shows you updated your answer but I can't view it. Can you email me directly?  Amber.k.77@hotmail.com

Comment: I followed your instructions and it says there is an error with the second line of the formula provided - and I went to go back to the example you sent so I could export and import the macro but it is gone now - can you re-send to me?  I would appreciate it so much!!  Or can you email me directly at my address stated above?  Thanks!!!!!